# object containing smart pointer to itself that isn't reset before object goes out of scope

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr

Ran into this bug where a class contains a pointer to itself -- and it was pointing to the same instance. Here is the smallest code snippet that contains that problem...

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node()
    {
        std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Node()
    {
        std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
    }

    void storeChild(boost::shared_ptr<Node> ptr)
    {
        m_ptr = ptr;
    }

private: 
    boost::shared_ptr<Node> m_ptr;
};

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Node> bc_ptr(new Node());
    bc_ptr->storeChild(bc_ptr); // this line is the bug 
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:
1. Is the Node object ever deleted? I know smart pointers are supposed to manage those things so we don't have to delete. But it looks like the reference that's passed into the class using `storeChild` never is reset. Does this mean I'm going to have a memory leak? 
2. Is there a way to use smart pointers that prevents this from happening? Clearly the `storeChild` method should be given a pointer to a different Node but how do you prevent that?

If I run this program, the destructor never gets called.

Comment: The Node object is never deleted because it holds itself. 
I would start by adding `assert(this != ptr.get())` in your storeChild method. This is a programmer's mistake and you can't really prevent it from happening. On a side note, if you expect the node to actually own its child, consider using a unique_ptr.

Comment: `boost::shared_ptr` now has a standard analogue called [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a memory leak since the shared pointer in `Node` never will be deleted. Consider:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Node {
    std::shared_ptr<Node> m_ptr;

public:
    Node() { std::cout << "constructor\n"; }
    ~Node() { std::cout << "destructor\n"; }
    void storeChild(std::shared_ptr<Node> ptr) { m_ptr = ptr; }
    long use_count() { return m_ptr.use_count(); }
};

int main() {   
    Node* n = new Node;
    {
        std::shared_ptr<Node> bc_ptr(n);
        bc_ptr->storeChild(bc_ptr); // this line is the bug

        std::cout << n->use_count() << "\n";     // prints 2
    }
    std::cout << n->use_count() << "\n";         // prints 1

    // the Node pointed to by n is leaked
}
```

It's probably even more obvious if you do like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Node {
    std::shared_ptr<Node> m_ptr;

public:
    Node() : m_ptr(this) { std::cout << "constructor\n"; }
    ~Node() { std::cout << "destructor\n"; }
};

int main() {
    new Node;
}
```

If you try:

```
int main() {
    delete new Node;
}
```

The `Node` destructor will be called twice. First by your `delete` and secondly by the `shared_ptr` when it's deleted.

Preventing it can be tricky if it's possible to end up with circular ownership, like: A->B->C->A ... You should probably use `std::weak_ptr` if that's a risk.